# canvas not visible on the browser(using atom text editor)

Tags: html, p5.js

I've just setup atom and installed p5.js packages.
it is running but canvas is not visible.
sketch.js

```
 function setup() {
createcanvas(200,200)
canvas.style("visibility", "visible")
// put setup code here
}
function draw() {
 // put drawing code here
 background(0);
 rect(100,100,50,50);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>p5.js example</title>
<style>
  body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<script src="libraries/p5.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/p5.sound.js"></script>
<script src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

on running it using atom editor the canvas is not visible on the browser screen

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to capitalize the second c in `createCanvas(width, height);`
2. You can't use `canvas.style("visibility", "visible")`, so remove that line

3.For future reference, inspect the page and look at the console, I found both of these things from errors.

> ```
> function setup() {
> createcanvas(200,200)//on this line, capitalize the c in canvas
> canvas.style("visibility", "visible")//remove this line
> // put setup code here
> }
> ```

Your html is all correct

Answer (score 0):

@Hgbanana is correct. I thinks it would be better if you put your library scripts in the head tag to make sure the libraries load before the page. But it should work anyways.